# Intellij: Running python script errors - Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea

This is for windows Intellij.

1. I have my add the plugin - org.codehaus.mojo in MVN pom file for setting PYTHONPATH environmentVariables.
2. Installed Python plugin.
3. Added the python interpretor to the project.

And when I run a simple python program with below 2 lines it errors:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
print("testing")
```

errors :

```
C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/name/IdeaProjects/projectName/src/main/resources/pythonlib/test.py
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1096, in _path_importer_cache
KeyError: 'C:\\Users\\name\\.m2\\repository\\info\\cukes\\cucumber-java\\1.2.2\\cucumber-java-1.2.2.jar'
```

I have set the environmental variable PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH and added path.

This is a maven project and created the python file under src/main/resources/pythonlib.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this plugin configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>python-build</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe</executable>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/pythonlib/</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>test.py</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't seem to help

Comment: How do you run your script? Do you use "exec" goal?

Comment: I run from Intellij Run Menu, where the configuration has Python Interpreter pointing to  C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
and the Working directory C:\Users\name\IdeaProjects\src\main\resources\pythonlib

Comment: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1074, in _path_hooks
NotImplementedError: bootstrap issue: python36.zip contains non-ASCII filenames without the unicode flag

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: I have set the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME in the windows environmental variables.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with run configuration?

Comment: Hi, I have created a new project and added the above to the pom file. Its is running fine under the new project but errors in the old one. I think it is related to the project specific.

Comment: Is it possible to share project for investigation?